# query to extract all rows inserted/updated from different tables

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I wrote a vb.net code who updates a mysql database.

To check that code works correctly I added a field "Updated" in each table of database containing the timestamp of inserting (o updating).

I can easly extract updated rows from each table but I wonder if it's possible to extract all updated rows with only one query.

Note that tables have different fields and different number of fields (so I wasn't able to use UNION).

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: can you provide some code? did you try SELCT ..  UNION ?

Comment: @CristiC777 I actually use `SELECT * FROM a_table_name WHERE Updated > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)` for each table. I wrote in the question that I tryed with `UNION` but it doesn't work becouse of different number of fields

Comment: I don't think the number o fields is the problem with UNION .. if all tables has defined filed : 'Updated' like you said .. ("added a field "Updated" in each table of database") , so every SELECT .. has his own Update filed in each table ..

Comment: also check in all your tables if Update field is datetime or timestamp .. >>>   and format ..

Answer (score 0):

so first 2 ideas:
1) **Select Union** 
ex:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_name_1 
WHERE Updated > '20.07.2015'  
UNION  
SELECT * FROM Table_name_2 
WHERE Updated > '20.07.2015'  
UNION  
SELECT * FROM Table_name_3 
WHERE Updated > '20.07.2015'
```

2) and if you have 200 tables.. the most advanced , that will need some tests

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('Product')
AND TABLE_SCHEMA='YourDatabase';
```

and you need to create a cursor  like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE curdemo()
   BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE a CHAR(16);
  DECLARE b, c INT;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id,data FROM test.t1;
  DECLARE cur2 CURSOR FOR SELECT i FROM test.t2;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cur1;
  OPEN cur2;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO a, b;
    FETCH cur2 INTO c;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    IF b < c THEN
      INSERT INTO test.t3 VALUES (a,b);
    ELSE
      INSERT INTO test.t3 VALUES (a,c);
    END IF;
   END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur1;
  CLOSE cur2;
END;
```

have fun ! and google hard !

Answer (score 0):

ok test this fidlle : [fiddle with 3 tables](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7bf4c/1)

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(`id` int, `productName` varchar(10), `Updated` datetime(6));
INSERT INTO table1  (`id`, `productName`, `Updated`)
VALUES
(1, 'OpenIM', '2015-07-21 13:58:01'),
(2, 'OpenAM', '2015-07-20 10:42:01'),
(3, 'OpenDJ', '2015-07-19 12:22:01')
;

CREATE TABLE table2
(`id` int, `productName` varchar(10), `Updated` datetime(6));
INSERT INTO table2  (`id`, `productName`, `Updated`)
VALUES
(1, 'OpenIMaa', '2015-07-21 21:58:01'),
(2, 'OpenAMbb', '2015-07-21 09:42:01'),
(3, 'OpenDJbb', '2015-07-20 07:22:01')
;

CREATE TABLE table3
(`id` int, `productName` varchar(10), `Updated` datetime(6));
INSERT INTO table3  (`id`, `productName`, `Updated`)
VALUES
(1, 'DDOpenIM', '2015-07-21 11:58:01'),
(2, 'FFOpenAM', '2015-07-21 10:42:01'),
(3, 'GGOpenDJ', '2015-07-19 12:22:01')
;
```

Build schema

```
 SELECT * FROM table1
 WHERE Updated >= subdate(current_date, 1)
 UNION
 SELECT * FROM table2
 WHERE Updated >= subdate(current_date, 1)
 UNION 
 SELECT * FROM table3
 WHERE Updated >= subdate(current_date, 1);
```

**Execute SQL**

```
 | id | productName |                Updated |
 |----|-------------|------------------------|
 |  1 |      OpenIM | July, 21 2015 13:58:01 |
 |  2 |      OpenAM | July, 20 2015 10:42:01 |
 |  1 |    OpenIMaa | July, 21 2015 21:58:01 |
 |  2 |    OpenAMbb | July, 21 2015 09:42:01 |
 |  3 |    OpenDJbb | July, 20 2015 07:22:01 |
 |  1 |    DDOpenIM | July, 21 2015 11:58:01 |
 |  2 |    FFOpenAM | July, 21 2015 10:42:01 |
```

Have fun !

Comment: If you change the first table this way: CREATE TABLE table1
 (`id` int, `productName` varchar(10), `Productid` int, `Updated` datetime(6));
INSERT INTO table1  (`id`, `productName`, `Productid`, `Updated`)
VALUES
 (1, 'OpenIM', 1, '2015-07-21 13:58:01'),
 (2, 'OpenAM', 2, '2015-07-20 10:42:01'),
 (3, 'OpenDJ', 3, '2015-07-19 12:22:01'); You'll see that doesn't work